# Scope of variable inside 'if' statement inside 'for loop' inside a function

Tags: c#, global-variables, nested-loops, local-variables

I am programming my robot in Atmel Studio 6.2, and I am programming a function to return the position of a black line on a white surface, which my robot can detect with 8 analog light sensors. I have researched thoroughly about scopes of variables in C#, however, I can't figure out what I have done wrong or misunderstood in this very simple piece of code below. When calling the functions underneath, then

this works:

```
char linePosDigital(int threshold)
{   
    char linePos = 0;

    if(analog_read(0) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 0);
    if(analog_read(1) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 1);
    if(analog_read(2) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 2);
    if(analog_read(3) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 3);
    if(analog_read(4) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 4);
    if(analog_read(5) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 5);
    if(analog_read(6) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 6);
    if(analog_read(7) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 7);

    return linePos;
}
```

this doesn't work:

```
char linePosDigital(int threshold)
{   
    char linePos = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(analog_read(i) < threshold) linePos += pow(2, i);
    }

    return linePos;
}
```

I need to make various functions somewhat similar to the one above, where I need to be able to use a for loop. After hours of research I still have no clue why the second mentioned function does not work.

Help is much needed and appreciated! (:

EDIT: This is my new MWE (you will need to change the print and delay commands as well as remove the library, sorry for that). linePosDigital1 outputs a correct answer, while linePosDigital2 outputs an incorrect answer:

```
#include <pololu/orangutan.h>

char linePosDigital1(int n[8], int threshold)
{   
    char linePos = 0;

    if(n[0] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 0);
    if(n[1] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 1);
    if(n[2] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 2);
    if(n[3] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 3);
    if(n[4] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 4);
    if(n[5] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 5);
    if(n[6] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 6);
    if(n[7] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, 7);

    return linePos;
}

char linePosDigital2(int n[8], int threshold)
{
    char linePos = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(n[i] < threshold) linePos += pow(2, i);
    }

    return linePos;
}

int main()
{
    int n[8];

    n[0] = 800;
    n[1] = 800;
    n[2] = 800;
    n[3] = 800;
    n[4] = 800;
    n[5] = 800;
    n[6] = 200;
    n[7] = 200;

    while(1)
    {
        clear();
        print_binary(linePosDigital1(n, 650));
        delay(1000);
        clear();
        print_binary(linePosDigital2(n, 650));
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

n is a static number which in this case represents a realistic input from my sensors.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I am calling the function with a built-in-function that prints the decimal input as a binary representation on the robot's LCD (print_binary(linePosDigital(650));). Thereby the robot (when using the working function) prints 8 0's and 1's, where a 0 represents white and a 1 represents black. However, the results are not correct when calling the non-working function. For example, when the working function returns 10000000 the non working function returns 01111111, and when the working function returns 11000000 the non-working function returns 10111110.

Comment: What is the purpose of the analog_read function?

Comment: @sovemp, the purpose is to read the analog input received from the photoresistors. The incoming voltage is represented in a 10-bit format ranging from 0 to 1023.

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but my guess is that the looping takes longer to execute than the hard-coded calls.  Since the timing is different, could this cause the discrepancy?

Comment: Neither of your code blocks compile because of the statement `char linePos = 0`.  But even with `char` changed to `int` so it will build, there is no difference between those two methods.  Have you read the instructions on creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @sovemp, at this very moment I just tried putting in a delay(1); (pause for 1 millisecond) between every if-statement. It still works, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: @Gabriel as a side-note: instead of doing `linePos += pow(2, i);`, you can set bit flags in a better way using `linePos |= (char)(1 << i);`.

Comment: @BJMyers, now I just read it. I don't understand why it won't compile when using char instead of int. I can use int instead of course, the reason I am using char is because the maximum returned value won't exceed 256. I know my MWE arguably is not 100% complete and verifiable, but I believe this is the closest I can get since I am programming on a robot using a library for that purpose. Are you absolutely sure the two functions are identical? I have not messed up the scope of linePos?

Comment: @Gabriel If I change the function to use `int` instead of `char` (so that it compiles for me) I get the same results from both functions for the cases you specify.

Comment: @Gabrial Then you should be using `byte`.  In C# `char` is a UTF-16 character, meaning it's 16 bits and is meant to represent encoded text, not generic binary data.

Comment: @Alex, thank you! I actually had been thinking about a way to optimize my code using bitwise operators. I will try that out.

Comment: @Gabriel  He is right that char linePos = 0 won't compile, because in C# 0 is an int literal.  Are you sure you're not using C++?

Comment: @BJMyers, I am sorry to hear that, that is just what I feared... Maybe the problem is another place then, even though I can't see how it could be.

Comment: @Kyle, I guess you are right, problem is I can't compile when using byte. It comes up with the error 'unknown type name 'byte''. I wonder why that is...?

Comment: @Gabriel With `byte` not being recognized and `char linePos = 0` working correctly, I strongly suspect you're not using C#.

Comment: @Gabriel You're probably not using C#, seeing as there's also a `pow` function which doesn't exist in C#.  The only way your code would be valid is if there were a `pow` method defined within the class that your example code is in.

Comment: @sovemp, I am using Atmel Studio 6.2, which is an IDE suitable for programming on Atmel microprocessors. The description can be found here: http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel_studio6/ It says that 'The Atmel Studio 6 IDP gives you a seamless and easy-to-use environment to write, build and debug your applications written in C/C++ or assembly code', so I am not sure really.

Comment: @Gabriel.  Yeah it sounds like you are using C++, which makes sense because your original code I think will compile in C++ but not C#.  As far as I can tell though there wouldn't be any scope issue.  Plus, if there were you should be getting an error.

Comment: Hi everyone, I think you are right. However it still does not describe why I experience a problem? I have edited my post with a new MWE which should be easy to compile for you, could you please try it and confirm whether you get the same output from both functions or not? Thanks in advance (:

Comment: PD. Sorry, forgot to declare variables with int instead of char! But for some reason I can't edit my post again...

Comment: @Alex, I should have used your elegant attempt much earlier - turned out the problem somehow has something to do with the `pow()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone, I finally solved the problem. I created a function for determining p^q and substituted this with the built-in-function pow(). This solved the problem, so I guess something was wrong with the pow() function - I still find that very weird though, especially because it is part of C(++), I guess? Anyway: thank you so much for your help and patience! :)

Comment: The `pow` function in c/c++ takes a `double` or `float` as its input and returns that type as its output. It won't work well if you try to use that return value to set a bit in a `char` variable by adding that return value to it. I am surprised that you did not get compiler errors or at least warnings about that.